# SSH Executing via PHP interrupted

Tags: php, video, ssh, ffmpeg

I've got something like Video uploader written in PHP. When application puts video into FTP server, application is executing ffmpeg to convert that video to .mp4 format:

```
if(ftp_put($connection, $file_name, $file, FTP_BINARY) == true) {
    ftp_close($connection);
    if($extension == 'mp4') {
        return redirect('/');
    } else {
        $ssh = new SSH2($server->ip);
        if (!$ssh->login($server->ssh_user, $server->ssh_pass)) {
            exit('Login Failed');
        } else {
            $ssh->exec('cd /var/www/videos/' . $video->id . ' && ffmpeg -i ' . $file_name . ' -c:v libx264 ' . $file_name_we . '.mp4');
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem is: video converting is being interuptted. How to make that ffmpeg is going to successfully convert a video to mp4 via PHP?**

Comment: interrupted by what?

Comment: may be **max_execution_time** is a reason. Not enough time to make processing

Comment: Well, I don't know. Convertning file is not converted correct. It is giving an mp4 file, but it is broken and it cannot be played. Is there any way to execute a script, redirect to homepage and server will converting that?

Comment: You should first of all locate the root cause of interruption of processing (or corruption of converted data) by manually executing the ffmpeg script on the server and watch output... If this seems to work fine, you in fact probably run into PHP script execution timeouts. Of course you could send processes to background. But better implement some simple queue type...

Comment: @matthias When I'm on server and type ffmpeg, it converts video succesfully.